# Optimization Problem [CALC I]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

This is a 2 parts problem.

1. Find (using **one** variable integrals) the area of a circular sector of raidius **r** and angle $\theta \leq\pi$.

So for this i used the expression:

$x^2 +y^2 = r^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

Taking the postivie root because of the angles i'm working with. Then, doing some calculation i ended up with the result $A=\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2$, being consistent with what i needed to find because it has to be half the area of a circle of raidius r.

The second part of the problem is where i don't know how to preceed.

2. A flower bed in the form of cirucular sector of radius **r** and $\theta \leq\pi$ will be made. The area is stipulated, it must be $A$. Find r and $\theta$ so that the perimeter of the flower bed is minimal.

So here, i don't know how to proceed as i don't know with which function i should be working, and it seems like a multivariable optimization problem, which is not the objective of the problem. Any hint? Is my original function wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac12\pi r^2$ isn't a function of $\theta$, so it comes out that the area is constant no matter what $\theta$ is -- which can't be right. (You're close though!)

As for converting a two-variable optimization problem into a one-variable optimization problem: you are optimizing perimeter, so you'll be taking the derivative of the perimeter function. To convert the perimeter function of $r$ and $\theta$ into a function of one variable only, use the relationship between $r$ and $\theta$ determined by the area function (the function which is being held constant).

Comment: Are you saying that the firts part of my problem i wrong? Maybe i misunderstood the problem. Am i not asked to find the area of a semicircle ?Or am i asking to find $A(\theta)$  where $\theta<\pi$. How would i do the lastest? Do i need to use a relationship between r and $\theta$ ?

Comment: @Karl You're being asked to find the area of a circular sector. If $\theta=\pi$ this is a semicircle, but for other values of $\theta$ this will not be a semicircle.

Comment: Yeah, i see my problem. But then starting from $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is wrong ? I'm lost, i mean i dont know how to start working.

Comment: @Karl Have you learnt the formula for integration to find area in polar coordinates?

Comment: Y.Forma, which formula would that be ? And onther thing, if instead of working with limit of integration 0 and $\pi$ i change them to 0 and $\theta$, would that work ? as in doing a change of variables and set $x=rcos(\theta)$

Comment: @Karl I was thinking of http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_polar.htm -- not sure if you saw it in Calc I though. The other way to do it is approximately what you described. Be careful, though, because that doesn't give you the whole area -- you also have to integrate under the line the segment $y=x\cos\theta$ -- draw some pictures to see why.

Comment: I did not remember that formula, i tried initially to use the fact that $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and so take the integral of $r^2 d\theta$ but never occured to me to multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ Would you link me the demostration of the formula ? Thanks

Comment: I have to integrate under the line segment $y=xcos(\theta)$ and then summ it to the another integral if theta > $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and substract it otherwise. right ?

Comment: @Karl Sounds right

Comment: I'm trying to do the optimization part but i keep going nowhere. I'm using the fact that $A=\frac{1}{2}r^2 \theta$ and that the perimeter (or arc lenght in this case) is $S=r \theta$, $A$ being constant. I use the relationship between $A$ and $\theta$ or between $A$ and $r$.

Comment: @Karl Hmm. I don't think you have the perimeter correct. Remember that the perimeter consists of more than just the arc.